# Question title font has changed

Tags: discussion, status-completed, design, fonts

The question title font has changed.  It is no longer Trebuchet MS but is now Helvetica.  Is this normal, or is there a problem?

**Edit (11/22/2011):** The font was reverted to Trebuchet MS.  Why was the font changed to begin with?

Comment: This may be related to the new user pages: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112151/new-user-page-live-on-meta

Comment: Helvetica is a problem? At least it's not Arial.

Comment: Awww; I preferred it before!

Comment: @BenBrocka: At least it's not Comic Sans!

Comment: @Asylum Yeah, that'd look slick! Put the Meta StackOverflow logo in papyrus...that design will really pop!

Comment: Shoot, the site is now mixing Helvetica and Arial. Not sure if I can stay in good conscience.

Comment: The change is driving me crazy

Comment: Why is this "not constructive"?

Comment: Trebuchet is back now?

Comment: Dang it, I liked the new font.

Comment: @waffles — So what's the reason for changing it again?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Close. It appears to be `'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif` (Arial is a fallback)

[image: Freehand Circled CSS]

[Apparently badp thinks it changed also](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/762442#762442)

(I'm sure there's a way to tell if it changed. Besides asking Jin, of course)

I did find a way to find out besides asking Jin... I asked [Tim Stone](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/150235/tim-stone) `:-D` According to him,

> h1{font-family:Trebuchet MS,Liberation Sans,DejaVu Sans,sans-serif;font-weight:bold;font-size:170%;margin-bottom:7px;}
>
> Was the old h1 definition

I still am not sure why it matters, though... :-)

Comment: Don't be afraid to [ask Jin](http://twitter.com/#!/jzy/status/136269306961985536).  :)

Comment: It matters because some of us get used to things like fonts! Typography is a _big_ deal in UI.

Answer (score 7):

Looks deliberate from the stylesheets, and it affects a few other areas too.

If you don't like it and you're running Firefox, add this to your userContent.css:

```
@-moz-document domain(stackoverflow.com) {
   h1, h2, h3 a.question-hyperlink, input[type=button], input[type=submit] {
      font-family: "Trebuchet MS" !important;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't appear to be anything mentioned specifically in the [Recent Changes list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange)...but really, little things change regularly...